# Terminal only shows $?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, command-line-interface

I recently set up a new user using "adduser username" on my server and noticed that when I login I get:

```
$
```

Also, with my new user there is no folder highlighting, or tab completion.

However when I login as root I get a full terminal prompt plus highlighting, completion etc.

```
root@lin01:~#
```

Anyone have any idea what I did wrong?

**Edit:** Solution was to type

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

While logged in with the $.

Comment: For me a password was requested on execution of the command. (the user-pw). As well to mention: you need to re-login to enable the new settings (debian-jessie)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your new user's login shell has been set to `/bin/sh`, which on Ubuntu is dash. This is a shell intended to be small and fast, to run scripts efficiently. It doesn't have any interactive features. Change your shell to zsh (better) or bash (more common):

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

If you want to change `adduser`'s default shell, edit `/etc/adduser.conf`:

```
DSHELL=/bin/bash
```

Comment: I tride typing chsh bash and it says "bash is not a user". So i typed "chsh username --shell bash" and it said "bash is an invalid shell". but I can type "bash" and it switches to the one i want. Any thoughts?

Comment: ok well, it turns out the correct command for me was: chsh -s /bin/bash .. thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: @kidcapital: Yes, `chsh -s /bin/bash` was right, I indicated the right command but messed up its syntax. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not using bash, but sh and your prompt is not set properly (if this is even possible with sh).

you can get your current shell by typing: **echo $SHELL**

if you want to start bash, just type **bash**